# adding js on joomla head

Tags: javascript, joomla, head

How I can implements below js on my joomla head section. I have tried several times to add this code but after modified on index.php file its not save on head section after review view page source its showing under body section.

```
     <script type='text/javascript'>
   (function() {
     var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
     var src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
         '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
     document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
   })();
 </script>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
 googletag.cmd.push(function() {
 googletag.defineSlot('/20819282/mpbd_top_header', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1452863082329-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
 googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
 googletag.enableServices();
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: You need to provide more info. Which file is index.php. And how does it look? Is it in your template, then what template are you using, etc.

Comment: Yes it is my template index.php  file where i am trying to add above js on head section. I am using joomla default protostar template.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code to /templates/{yourtemplate}/index.php in the head section, and the code will show up in the head section. If you are using some special template, then things can be a little more complex, but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change code in the default protostar template. After the next Joomla update, your changes will be wiped out.

Since this most likely is not the only change you want to do to the template, first of all, create a copy of the template, rename it, install it and configure your Joomla to use it.  This will make the changes persist across updates.

Then spot the file templates/your_new_template_name/index.php and just before the end of the head section paste your code so it looks something like this

```
<script 
....
</script>
</head>
```

Maybe it could be easier for you to just add one of the extensions dedicated to handling in-page ads, there are plenty just search the JED: http://extensions.joomla.org/category/ads-a-affiliates  . This will take care of all the code you need, and you can concentrate on your ads campaigns.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. i tried above process(rename template) but No result its still in body section. Do you suspect anything else ? My url: http://www.mobilepricebd.net

Comment: I suggest you post on the joomla.stackexchange site, as stackoverflow is really for developers, whilst there you might find more support. But do go ahead and grab a dedicated extension, it's easier and more effective; and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Download this module from the JED: [Flexi Custom Code](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/flexi-custom-code) and install it.

Create a new file called myscript.js

Add the following lines to myscript.js and save it to the web root of your server (/public_html/)

```
(function() {
 var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
 var src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
     '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
 document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
 })();

googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.defineSlot('/20819282/mpbd_top_header', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1452863082329-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
googletag.enableServices();
});
```

In the backend go to Extensions > Modules and click on the empty entry for the Flexi Code module.

Set the position to debug, set the module title to MY SCRIPT (or wahtever you want to name it, and set the title to hidden

There are 4 options below the code box, leave the first option to use PHP toggled on and turn the other 3 off.

Enter this text into the code box:
    `<?php`
    $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addScript("myscript.js", "text/javascript");
    `?>`

This will add the myscript.js file as an include in the HEAD of the current template without the need for editing the template file itself.

The entire process should take less than 5 minutes.